# Matching values in python between two csv files

Tags: python, csv, comparison

I have two CSV files that I need to pull out the correct matches from.  I want to compare each row from the first file and state whether it has a matching value at any row in file two.  If a match is found it sound move on to the next row in fileOne and repeat.

Below is the code I have so far, but it only seems to be making a comparison directly between each files rows.  So the first row in file one is only compared against the first row in file two, instead of looping through all rows in file two until a match or no match is found.

I suspect it has something to do with how I have set up my for loops but I am unsure.

```
import csv

fileOne = csv.reader(open("fileone.csv", "r"))
fileTwo = csv.reader(open("filetwo.csv", "r"))

for row1 in fileOne:
    for row2 in fileTwo:
        row1String = row1[1].upper() + row1[0].upper()
        row2String = row2[1].upper() + row2[0].upper()

        if row1String == row2String:
            print "Matched %s, %s, %s" % (row1[1], row2[1], row1[0])
            break
        else:
            print "No Match, %s" % (row1[0])
            break
```

Comment: `csv.reader` is an iterator - try e.g. `fileOne = list(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Shift your last `else` block as an `else` block for your `for loop`. So your `for loop` would look like:-

```
file2items = [row2 for row2 in fileTwo]
for row1 in fileOne:
    for row2 in file2items:
        row1String = row1[1].upper() + row1[0].upper()
        row2String = row2[1].upper() + row2[0].upper()

        if row1String == row2String:
            print "Matched %s, %s, %s" % (row1[1], row2[1], row1[0])
            break
    else:
        print "No Match, %s" % (row1[0])
        break
```

You would conclude that "No matches were found", only after iterating over whole of your 2nd file. This `else` block would trigger if the for loop never breaks during its iteration(i.e no matches were found).

Comment: This still leaves the problem that `fileOne` and `fileTwo` are iterators, so will be consumed the first time they're iterated over.